# Combine %USERPROFILE% in path

Tags: c#, path, temp

I need help adding current logged %USER% to the path, this is my code so far:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\TEST");
foreach (FileInfo files in dir.GetFiles())
{
     files.Delete();
}
foreach (DirectoryInfo dirs in dir.GetDirectories())
{
    dirs.Delete(true);
}
```

how can I make him read %USERPROFILE% as current user?
I would love an example to figure things out, btw I want to use it to delete C:\Document and settings\%USERPFORILE%\Local Settings\Temp

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to add that while `Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile` is a good answer to your specific question, there's also another option that works for all environment variables, not just those that have a `SpecialFolder` accessor: [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It will take a string, like your `@"%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\TEST"`, and return a new string with  all %% environment variables expanded.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
void Main()
{
    string userProfile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
    string subFolder = @"Local Settings\TEST";
    string path = Path.Combine(userProfile, subFolder);

    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    if (di.Exists)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Deleting " + di);
        di.Delete(true);//recursive
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Directory " + di + " was not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Im getting:
"system.environment.specialfolder does not contain a definition for 'userprofile'"
why is that?

Comment: You're getting the error (as of your comment to Raj Rao) because you're denied access to the "Local Settings" folder ... It's protected.

Comment: @user2681588 The `UserProfile` member appears to have been added to the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration in .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you actually want:

```
String appData = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

Use that instead of the Code `Local Setting` folder if you want to store data or do something.

(as my comment said, the Local setting folder is protected and that way you won't be able to open it)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables

```
void Main() {
        string path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\TEST");

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        foreach (FileInfo files in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            files.Delete();
        }
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dirs in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            dirs.Delete(true);
        }
    }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables.aspx

Comment: how would this work for a different server? instead of (@"%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\ I would need this to access a different machine to get the information.